# What causes some women to have repeated abortions?

Tags: social-psychology, developmental-psychology, sexuality, health-psychology

Fisher et al. (2005) studied the characteristics of women who have repeated abortions. The study was conducted in countries where reliable contraception and education about birth control are readily available. There appears to be a link between a history of physical or sexual abuse and women who have repeated abortions.

However, not all women having repeated abortions have been abused. Another factor must come into play for non-abused women having repeated abortions.

Thus, my question is:

**What other factors besides physical and sexual abuse cause some women to have repeated abortions?**

Some examples might include poor living skills, lack of education, low self esteem, self abuse, socioeconomic conditions, a true desire to have a baby, ambiguity about wanting a child, fear of being a bad parent, fear of being tied to an abusive partner, lack of responsibility etc. This list is by no means exhaustive.

#### References

- William A. Fisher, Sukhbir S. Singh, Paul A. Shuper, Mark Carey, Felicia Otchet, Deborah MacLean-Brine, Diane Dal Bello, and Jennifer Gunter   **[Characteristics of women undergoing repeat induced abortion](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC550633/)  CMAJ. 2005 March 1; 172(5): 637–641.**

Comment: Thanks JeromyAnglim! It looks much better to me. What do you think now @what?

Comment: @JoshGitlin Same here. What do you think of my additional edits?

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I took your edits a bit further. Please roll back, if you disagree.

Comment: Looks fine to me @what! Skippy, do you feel the original intent of your question has remained intact?

Answer (score 2):

It is certain that a desire to have sex without contraception and a lack of desire to be a parent cause women to have multiple abortions. (precluding rape)

1. A certain amount of a desire to have sex is natural. Causes for increased sexuality are so numerous that is not tenable to search.
2. Risk taking behaviour is associated with sex without contraceptions. A stable long term relationship might be one reason to have sex without protection where the risk is perceived to be less based on the lack of infidelity. A lack of responsibility could also motivate someone to consistently not use protection. Peer pressure by the male or even religion is also possible.
3. Finally there are many reasons people decide not to be a parent. Primarily they are unable to be a mentor and they are incapable of nurturing. There are many additional reasons at this link about [why certain reasons to have children are irrational](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/complete-without-kids/201209/six-great-reasons-never-have-children). However it should be stated that just because one is incapable of being a good parent doesn't leave abortion as the only option. The child can be given up for adoption however that is not popular.